# npm "install" location in Visual Studio; .Net Core app

Tags: visual-studio-2017, npm-install

I'm just starting to play with my first .Net Core applications and am trying to use npm for client-side libraries. They get added to node_modules but aren't "installed" to wwwroot.
My question appears to have been asked before without answers:

- [How do I include libraries that installed via NPM to my MVC project on Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907027/how-do-i-include-libraries-that-installed-via-npm-to-my-mvc-project-on-visual-st)

I've tried to install [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs). That works insofar that the files are downloaded and added to the node_modules folder:

- projectfolder

  - node_modules

    - cropperjs

      - dist
      - src
      - package.json, changelog, readme, license etc. files

Now how would I get these files into my wwwroot directory to use them? The documentation is slightly confusing I'm afraid.
Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found the answers after seeing the list of "related questions" to my own.
apparently, it is indeed required to copy the required files and folders over to the wwwroot location. 
These two questions yielded answers and comments that solve my question:

[How to access node_modules folder from wwwroot in asp.net vnext project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527001/how-to-access-node-modules-folder-from-wwwroot-in-asp-net-vnext-project)

[How to use npm with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935524/how-to-use-npm-with-asp-net-core?rq=1)